# Definite Integral of a Divergent Integrand

Tags: calculus, integration

Earlier today, I was in Calculus and I thought of these two integrals.

1. Is $\int_{-∞}^{∞} \frac{1}{x^3} dx = 0$ ?

Could this be 0, as the left and right sides are equal in area but opposite in signs when the intervals are equidistant from x = 0? Or is this an issue as the intervals are not defined (i.e a number)?

2. Is $\int_{1}^{3} \frac{1}{x-2} dx = 0$ ?

About the same case with this, except that the intervals are equidistant from x = 2 and that the intervals are defined.

Edit:

Upon further research, I have discovered a method called the Cauchy Principle Value which relates to improper integral. Can someone explain the purpose / way by it works?

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{x-2} dx = \ln (x-2)$$

Evaluating at $3$ gives a real solution, evaluating at $1$ gives a complex solution, so it can't evaluate to $0$. For the other problem, what happens as $x \to 0$?

Comment: Hm, do we use absolute value when taking the integral of 1/(x-2)? For the first problem, as x approaches 0, the value goes to infinity or negative infinity depending whether you're referring to the integrand or antiderivative.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. I was helping someone on another question that was dealing with complex eigenvectors and got confused between the problems. In the $\ln(x-2)$ case, the problem doesn't converge either as you are integrating over a singular point.

Comment: Can you have a definite integral with a converge antiderivative?